# How to get Google Search results from an application back-end?

Tags: java, android, api, google-api

I want to be able to retrieve Google search results and use it in an application I am developing?

For example when you type "movies" 
Google now app will return result like this 
[image]
I want to be able to get these movies suggestions.

Also for each movie it can give you times in cinemas around you. How can I access such results from Google through an API or something?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use google custom search API ... 
Check this out 
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview

You can use this to search the entire web through a hack 
To create a Google Custom Search engine that searches the entire web:

EDIT:

- From the Google Custom Search homepage ( http://www.google.com/cse/ ), click Create a Custom Search Engine.
- Type a name and description for your search engine.
- Under Define your search engine, in the Sites to Search box, enter at least one valid URL (For now, just put www.anyurl.com to get past this screen. More on this later ).
- Select the CSE edition you want and accept the Terms of Service, then click Next. Select the layout option you want, and then click Next.
  Click any of the links under the Next steps section to navigate to your Control panel.
- In the left-hand menu, under Control Panel, click Basics.
  In the Search Preferences section, select Search the entire web but emphasize included sites.
- Click Save Changes.
- In the left-hand menu, under Control Panel, click Sites.
- Delete the site you entered during the initial setup process.

Comment: From what I understand.. This api is used to implement search in your own website.. Am I wrong?.. Me Goal is to get Google Search results itself

Comment: Yeah this solution works.. in terms of getting the results. But my aim is the first block (the one with movies posters) this doesn't show when using the method you mentioned.Thanks though.